# R - (Tidyverse) Turn one row into multiple rows based on column integer

Tags: r, tidyverse

Let's say that I have a dataset which consists of multiple observations. Sometimes a single observation is actually multple ones that have been condensed into one. To keep track of how many observations were merged together an integer-valued variable exists.

What I want to do is to reverse this process.

**Example code:**

```
library(tidyverse)

# Example tibble
df_ex <- tibble(
  var1 = seq(1, 3),
  var2 = c('Some', 'Random', 'Text'),
  var3 = c(1, 3, 2)
)
```

The code above produces the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   var1 var2    var3
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 Some       1
2     2 Random     3
3     3 Text       2
```

The desired tibble after some tidyverse magic would be:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   var1 var2    var3
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 Some       1
2     2 Random     1
3     2 Random     1
4     2 Random     1
5     3 Text       1
6     3 Text       1
```

Comment: Many ways `df_ex %>% group_by(var1) %>% mutate(var3 = list(rep(1, var3))) %>% unnest`  or `df_ex %>% mutate(var3 = map(var3, ~ rep(1, .x))) %>% unnest` or `transform(df_ex[rep(seq_len(nrow(df_ex)), df_ex$var3),], var3 = 1)` in `base R`

Comment: Very nice! Do you want to write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this in `tidyverse`

**1)**  Do a group by 'var1' (assuming it is unique), create a `list` column for 'var3' by replicating 1 with the value of 'var3' and then `unnest`

```
df_ex %>%
      group_by(var1) %>% 
      mutate(var3 = list(rep(1, var3))) %>%
      unnest
```

**2)** Use `map` to get the `list` column for 'var3' and `unnest`

```
df_ex %>%
    mutate(var3 = map(var3, ~ rep(1, .x))) %>%
    unnest
```

**3)**  With `base R`, replicate the sequence of rows to expand the data and then `transform` the 'var3' to 1

```
transform(df_ex[rep(seq_len(nrow(df_ex)), df_ex$var3),], var3 = 1)
```